# Unable to deploy a network from my local Hyperledger Composer playground

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I installed Hyperleder Composer on my local machine follow on this https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html

After I started the fabric and playground. The deploy button wasn't able to click.

[The button is gray and I can't click it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6gok.png)

Answer (score 2):

Give the name of network admin card and scroll down to credentials for network administrator and change them as displayed in below image.

you can find your answer here
[image]